# Solve: $y'(x+y-3)= x+2y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is a general solution to the differential equation: $y'(x+y-3)= x+2y$?

Comment: Just a comment: When I put it in wolfram alpha, wolfram alpha could solve it up to an implicit class of solutions. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27(x%2By-3)%3Dx%2B2y

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

$y'(x+y-3) = x+2y$

$ (x+y =3) $ and $(x+2y=0)$ give us a solution $x=6, y=-3$. So let's substitute $u = x-6, v=y+3$. We get $y' = v'$ and our equation has a form:

$v'( (u+6) + (v-3) - 3) = (u + 6) + 2(v-3)$

So

$v'(u+v) = u+2v$

Kinda better, but we're not yet succeded. Dividing by $u+v$, we get:

$v' = \frac{u+2v}{u+v} = \frac{ 2\frac{v}{u} + 1}{\frac{v}{u} + 1} $

Now substitute $ w = \frac{v}{u} $ (I want $v,w$ to be a function of $u$ ). We get $w'u + w=(wu)' = v'$

And that means our equation: $(w'u + w) = \frac{2w+1}{w+1}$, so

$w' = \frac{-w^2+w+1}{(w+1)u}$

$\int \frac{w+1}{-w^2 +w +1}dw = ln(u) + C_1, \ $ where $ \ C_1\in \mathbb R$

So we have to solve $\int \frac{w+1}{-w^2 +w +1}dw = -\int \frac{w+1}{(w - \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})(w - \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})}dw = H(w) + C_2$

And it is solveable (partial fractions). Then you get something of form $H(w) = ln(u) +C$, going back to $x,y$ we get:

$H(\frac{v}{u}) = \ln(x-6) + C$

$H(\frac{y+3}{x-6}) = \ln(x-6) + C$